# How much did Date A Live anime cover the Light Novel?

Tags: date-a-live

I finished the anime, so I was thinking to start reading the light novel but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the [Wikia](http://date-a-live.wikia.com/wiki/Light_Novel_and_Manga), which says that:

> **In April 2013, an anime adaptation began which covered the events of volumes 1-4 of the light novel** which ended in June 2013. A dub of season 1 was released on 10th June 2014 by FUNimation. **A second season aired on 11th April, 2014 to 13th June, 2014 which covers the events from volumes 5-7.**